# ListView not showing any item. (from SlidingMenu to NavigationDrawer)

Tags: android, custom-adapter, navigation-drawer

I got an app which was using the SlidingMenu Library from JFeinstein.
I was using a custom adapter for the navigation ListView. I didn't have any issues.

Since the new SupportLibrary version introduced ActionBarCompat and NavigationDrawer I wanted to get rid of ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu because I think it's a cleaner solution to depend on "official" libraries.
Today I wanted to swap the SlidingMenu library with the NavigationDrawer. I left the Adapter untouched, changed the main_activity.xml like in the official tutorial on d.android.com explained.

BUT there is no item rendered in the ListView. The sliding works great but I cannot see any items. I did not have changed anything on the adapter because it worked great on the SlidingMenu library. Adapter#getCount() returns 10 - so it's definitly not empty. I also called Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged() to be sure that all items will get rendered, but Adapter#getView(...) is never called.

If I put another ListView onto the MainActivity's layout (into the RelativeLayout which represents my content) this ListView also does not show any items.
I copied some basic Adapter examples which work with SimpleAdapter but even with this one, no ListView shows any items!

My code in my activity:

```
private void setupSidemenu() {
        // init sidemenu ui
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findView(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        menuAdapter = new SideMenuAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        list.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I am using AndroidAnnotations and somehow I've overriden the Activity#onCreate(Bundle) but also specified an layout at the @EActivity(R.layout.xxx) annotation. For some reasons #setupSidemenu() was called but effected another listview? which was not show?
The exact reason is still unclear to me but I am now using @AfterViews and my ListView is filled.